# Dual FireWire External HDD and second port performance

Tags: macbook-pro, external-disk, firewire

Backstory: There is a drive that comes to mind out there that has two FireWire 800 ports.  My question is related to performance of the second port.  In my case, I would like to hook up an external sound card to my MacBook Pro.  I am already maxing out my USB ports with other devices and I and using Thunderbolt to power another display.  So my only option is to use FireWire, which is the choice anyways.

Question: Will using a dual FireWire 5400 RPM HDD with the additional port (daisy chain) affect the stability, quality or bus speed to the external sound card?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't. FireWire is a peer to peer technology